# after connecting redis to django and docker, the data is not saved in redis-cli

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, redis

I connected redis to django and did docker-compose, redis itself works, but if I want to connect to the terminal via docker exec -it redis redis-cli, then it connects, but I can’t get any data and if I write the keys * command, then no data either (except for celery)

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env 
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    depends_on: 
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - db:db

  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    volumes:  
      - ./data/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${BD_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${BD_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${BD_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    expose:
      - '5432'
 
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: always
    container_name: redis
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A wishes worker -l INFO
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
      - db
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
 

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

redis-cli example

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get milan
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
2) "_kombu.binding.celery"
3) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
2) "_kombu.binding.celery"
3) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
127.0.0.1:6379> get kranf
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

And debug_tool

[debug_tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/touqw.png)

Comment: What does happen?  Can you show the exact commands you're running?  You believe the Django/Celery wiring is correct, are you seeing things like the application creating a task and the worker running it?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added redis-cli example and screenshot debug_tool. The problem is that I want to work with redis through the terminal to be sure that everything works, but even though redis works with django, the data is written out, but this data is not saved in the redis terminal in docker. For example, I’m trying to get get kranf, which I saved when entering the page in django, but there is no data, and if I do the get through the code in django itself on the views page, then there are no problems

Comment: Based on what you've shown, the Redis server is starting up, `redis-cli` can connect to it, and it seems like the Celery wiring is working.  Can you provide an example of the code that _isn't_ working?  (Why do you expect there to be more keys?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I save the cache, that's working, but in redis-cli i don't see anything 


`def redis_check(request):
    cache.set('milan', 'man', timeout=None)
    key_exists = cache.get('milan')
    return HttpResponse(f'<html><body><h1>{key_exists}</h1></body></html>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Redis` is empty its probably because

1- You forgot to set the **BACKEND** of **CACHES** setting to `django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache`. The default backend provided for CACHES is `django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` that store cache data into memory.

2- The common **LOCATION** is `redis://<host>:<port>/1` witch try to connect and interact with `db1` But ‍‍`redis-cli` connects to `db0` by default. Use the `-n` option of `redis-cli` to execute commands into specific database (db1 in your case): `redis-cli -n 1`

Comment: No, i already have it (

Comment: How about LOCATION? `redis-cli` usually connect to `db0` but the common LOCATION of CACHES settings in django is to `redis://<host>:<port>/1` that connect to `db1`.

Comment: My location looks like that

`"LOCATION": "redis://{}:{}/1".format(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)`

Comment: Use `-n` option of `redis-cli` to connect to specific database. `redis-cli -n 1` will connect to db1